# Какой стек технологий выбрать для приложения в трее под разные настольные ОС?

Tags: java, c#, c++, python, ос

Добрый день.

Хочу написать приложение, которое будет висеть в области уведомлений и так же иметь стандартное открывающееся окно с информацией и настройками. Настройки будут в файле в директории установки.
Должно работать под Винду, Линукс и Мак. 
Желательно чтобы выглядело одинаково.

Минимальный необходимый функционал это доступ к событиям мыши (клик, движения) и клавиатуры (нажатие).

(ОБРАТИТЕ ВНИМАНИЕ! Клики нужно получать абсолютно все в пределах ОС, а не только в программе.)

Так же нужно будет иметь доступ в Интернет и иметь возможность расшарить сообщение в соц. сети.

Сам я веб программист, под ОС опыта нету. 
Рассматриваю варианты Java + Java FX или Swing, C# + mono, c++ + QT или python. 
Какие ещё есть варианты?

Comment: tray - это понятие из Windows. более правильным вариантом будет назвать это Область уведомлений. и у всех систем там свои особенности.

Comment: спасибо, поправлю. особенности - это понятно. и все же какой стек лучше всего мне тут подойдет?

Comment: `Клики нужно получать абсолютно все в пределах ОС, а не только в программе` – как-то это уже похоже на троян ))

Comment: та нет)) это для фана и по сути для изучения программинга под ОС. придумал интересную идею и хочу реализовать. Юзеры будут предупреждены о сборе кликов)

Comment: @NickVolynkin как и отображение на экране всех нажимаемых клавиш или запись скринкаста со звуком с микрофона :) Многие полезные приложения можно считать похожими на троян, щито поделать)

Comment: Java и Python хороши, но лично я не поленился бы компилировать под каждую платформу что-нибудь с Qt (на C++ или Rust)

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что тут идеально подойдет *Java*. Собственно, почему:

1. *Java* работает под всеми платформами без перекомпиляции (C++ требует перекомпиляцию, С# вообще не сильно умеет работать под чем-то, кроме Windows'a, а если и умеет — с проблемами, Python — даже не знаю).
2. *Java* имеет инструмент (если не ошибаюсь, [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)), который считывает нажатия и координаты мышки в любой области экрана вне программы. Имеет проблемы с работой в DirectX играх, у меня не вышло получить цвет экрана в игре (мне было интересно, можно ли так написать чит — вышло, но не полностью :)).
3. *Java* имеет уйму библиотек для работы с сетью и, опять же, это работает одинаково везде.

Можете попробовать использовать Swing, на нем могут выйти действительно красивые вещи, но у меня всегда получалось море г***окода.. (только паттерны типа MVC и спасали), поэтому лучше посмотрите в сторону JavaFX.

Так же не упускайте из виду *Python*, я с ним не знаком, но, на сколько я знаю, он тоже может работать в виртуальной машине. Может он Вам и подойдет.

Comment: Посмотрел Robot, он похоже что-то вроде Selenium, только под десктоп. Т.е. для автоматизации тестирвоания и он может симулировать нажатия мыши и клавиш, но считывать - пока не нашел.

Comment: @ОлегАбражаев, значит все-таки перепутал. Есть какая-то библиотека, которая позволяет слушать нажатия. В этом профиле есть вопрос на эту тему, где дают название библиотеки — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189127/bukashka101?tab=topactivity